# Public Key Pinning (HPKP) max-age client side behavior

Tags: security, https, man-in-the-middle, pinning

I have not clear understanding of the purpose of the max-age directive in the RFC7469 (Public Key Pinning Extension)

My understanding of RFC7469 and HTTP Public Key Pinning is that every time a client starts an HTTPS transaction with a server, it should compute the pin of the server certificate and verify that it matches one of the pin returned by the server in a previous transaction. If pin does not match, than a man-in-the-middle event may have occurred and connection must be denied.

What is not clear to me is the purpose of "max-age" directive. This is what RFC7469 states:

The "max-age" directive specifies the number of seconds after the
   reception of the PKP header field during which the UA SHOULD regard
   the host (from whom the message was received) as a Known Pinned Host.

Does this mean that the client should update a local copy of pins not later than max-age expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max-age tells the client how long the HPKP header is valid for. After max-age expires the HPKP header should be forgotten and ignored. However if you revisit the site during that time you will likely get a new max-age and extend the max-age a little longer.

Certificates have a validity period so it does not make sense to make a HPKP header valid indefinitely. It’s also possible to block access to your site accidentally by updating certificate. So a max-age is necessary.

HPKP has been seen to be dangerous (see [my blog post here](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/) for some of the reasons), so even with a max-age it’s proven to be too dangerous for most sites and [Chrome for one are removing it as an option](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5903385005916160).